# Bind to function with an unknown number of arguments in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

Suppose I have an `std::function` that takes as input `N` arguments of type `T` (this can be constructed using some metaprogramming magic; see below), where `N` is a **template parameter**. I would like to `std::bind` the first argument to construct a function with `N-1` arguments (e.g. `myBind<...>(someValue)`). I could not think of a clever metaprogramming trick to do this. Any suggestions?

From [Lambda function with number of arguments determined at compile-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615843/lambda-function-with-number-of-arguments-determined-at-compile-time):

> You can write a template `n_ary_function` with a nested `typedef` type. This type can be used as  follows:
>
> ```
> template <int N> class A {
>     typename n_ary_function<N, double>::type func;
> };
> ```
>
> Following the definition of `n_ary_function`:
>
> ```
> template <std::size_t N, typename Type, typename ...Types>
> struct n_ary_function {
>     using type = typename n_ary_function<N - 1, Type, Type, Types...>::type;
> };
>
> template <typename Type, typename ...Types>
> struct n_ary_function<0, Type, Types...> {
>     using type = std::function<void(Types...)>;
> };
> ```

Comment: can you post your code that builds that `function` ?

Comment: @PiotrS.: I have put the code in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::bind` uses `std::is_placeholder` to detect placeholders, which means that you can write your own placeholders to use with `std::bind` by partially specializing `std::is_placeholder`:

```
template<int N>
struct my_placeholder { static my_placeholder ph; };

template<int N>
my_placeholder<N> my_placeholder<N>::ph;

namespace std {
    template<int N>
    struct is_placeholder<::my_placeholder<N>> : std::integral_constant<int, N> { };
}
```

This makes it possible to get a placeholder from an integer. The rest is simply the standard integer sequence trick:

```
template<class R, class T, class...Types, class U, int... indices>
std::function<R (Types...)> bind_first(std::function<R (T, Types...)> f, U val, std::integer_sequence<int, indices...> /*seq*/) {
    return std::bind(f, val, my_placeholder<indices+1>::ph...);
}
template<class R, class T, class...Types, class U>
std::function<R (Types...)> bind_first(std::function<R (T, Types...)> f, U val) {
    return bind_first(f, val, std::make_integer_sequence<int, sizeof...(Types)>());
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9b21ba0b6b62e42). `std::integer_sequence` is technically C++14, but it's easily implementable in C++11 - just search on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I already had an integer sequence generator for C++11 so this worked out quite well. I removed lines 7-8 (in the demo) also.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <functional>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <std::size_t N, typename Type, typename... Types>
struct n_ary_function
{
    using type = typename n_ary_function<N - 1, Type, Type, Types...>::type;
};

template <typename Type, typename... Types>
struct n_ary_function<0, Type, Types...>
{
    using type = std::function<void(Types...)>;
};

using placeholders_list = std::tuple<decltype(std::placeholders::_1)
                                   , decltype(std::placeholders::_2)
                                   , decltype(std::placeholders::_3)
                                   , decltype(std::placeholders::_4)
                                   , decltype(std::placeholders::_5)
                                   , decltype(std::placeholders::_6)
                                   , decltype(std::placeholders::_7)
                                   , decltype(std::placeholders::_8)
                                   , decltype(std::placeholders::_9)
                                   , decltype(std::placeholders::_10)
                                   >;

template <typename F>
struct arity;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct arity<std::function<R(Args...)>>
{
    static constexpr std::size_t value = sizeof...(Args);
};

template <typename F, typename T, std::size_t... Ints>
auto binder(F f, T t, std::index_sequence<Ints...>)
{
    return std::bind(f, t,
           typename std::tuple_element<Ints, placeholders_list>::type{}...);
}

template <typename F, typename T>
auto myBind(F f, T t)
{
    return binder(f, t, std::make_index_sequence<arity<F>::value - 1>{});
}
```

*Tests:*

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e)
{
    std::cout << a << b << c << d << e << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    n_ary_function<5, int>::type f = foo;
    n_ary_function<4, int>::type b = myBind(f, 1);
    b(2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f3c0b347f952333)